# What probability distribution matches $1/(e^x - 1)?$

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-family

I've been looking at the proof of [Planck's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law).

This is the first law that triggered the science of quantum theory by introducing the idea of quanta (which come in the form of packets of energy of size $h\nu$  - $h$ being Planck's constant and $\nu$ being the frequency).

The simplified form of the equation, that uses Planck's units, is:-

$$ B(\nu, T) = 2\nu^3\frac{1}{e^\frac{\nu}{T}-1}$$

In [the derivation](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Planck%20(1900),%20Distribution%20Law.pdf), Planck talks about a normal distribution.  I think the $\nu^3$ term in the equation is the part that represents the energy of the atom, and I've removed that as I'm really interested in the number of atoms of a certain frequency, rather than the total energy of those atoms.

My question is: what kind of distribution is being shown by a simplified form of the above equation:-

$$y =\frac{1}{e^{0.00000001x}-1}$$

The graph looks like this:

[image]

**NOTE**: I've multiplied the $x$ by $0.00000001$ to give an $x$ axis with numbers that look like frequencies, but the graph is the same without that.

I'm thinking that this graph is showing $y$ = the number of atoms at each of the frequencies on the x axis, but I'm trying to work out what statistical situation would lead to this kind of distribution.  I'm imagining that it's something like "the probability of an atom being frequency x is inverse of that frequency", but I don't know how to work it out.  I'm also thinking that someone who has a lot of experience of distributions may also recognise this equation.

Steve.

Comment: There is no such distribution, because the integral of this function diverges.  BTW, $h\nu$ is the energy, not $\nu^3.$

Comment: It reminds me the MB distribution, which is also energy-related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution